# update Pandas index after sorting

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas and python. I would like to update the index of my data-frame after sorting. but It is not working at all. Any clues would be most helpful.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'Odd':[1,3,5,6,7,9], 'Even':[0,2,42,6,8,10]})
data["colors"]=["red","orange","yellow","green","blue","indigo"]
data["oldindex"]=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
print(data.head(10))
data2 = (data.sort_values(by=["Even"], ascending = False))
data2.reset_index(drop=False)
print("-----------------")
print(data2.head(10))
print("-----------------")
```

this gives me the following output:

> ```
>    Odd  Even  colors  oldindex
> 0    1     0     red         0
> 1    3     2  orange         1
> 2    5    42  yellow         2
> 3    6     6   green         3
> 4    7     8    blue         4
> 5    9    10  indigo         5
> -----------------
>    Odd  Even  colors  oldindex
> 2    5    42  yellow         2
> 5    9    10  indigo         5
> 4    7     8    blue         4
> 3    6     6   green         3
> 1    3     2  orange         1
> 0    1     0     red         0
> -----------------
> ```

But the index of the first column doesn't change at all. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need assign back:

```
data2 = data2.reset_index(drop=False)
```

I think `inplace` is not good practice, check [this](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace) and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529). But if really want it is possible use:

```
data2.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
```